Ammo.js: Setup/import TypeErrors
I am trying to use three.js to write a program in which I can import a model file (likely .obj), turn it into a cloth/softbody and interact with it using my mouse (for example to pull at the cloth).
I have used the obj-importer and THREE.x successfully so far to import and look at an obj. Now I would like to turn the .obj into a softbody using ammo.js for the physics part. However, I am having trouble with the initialization: I either get a TypeError for my first instance calling on Ammo

Ammo.btSoftBodyRigidBodyCollisionConfiguration is a undefined


TypeError: Ammo.btSoftBodyRigidBodyCollisionConfiguration is not a constructor

or, when I try to initialize ammo.js in an asynchronous way using
Ammo().then((lib) => {
    Ammo = lib;
    init()
  });

the ouput is

Ammo: object


TypeError: Ammo is not a function

I followed the three.js installation on the three.js website and downloaded ammo.js using npm install github:kripken/ammo.js. I use vite for the localhost.
I feel like I’m missing something with the ammo.js import, but I’ve looked at ammo.js example codes, searched around both the three.js-forum and stackoverflow, asked ChatGPT and not really found a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I use the following code:
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ammo.js Softbody-OBJ</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./node_modules/ammo.js/builds/ammo.wasm.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

main.js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as Ammo from '../node_modules/ammo.js/builds/ammo.wasm.js';

let scene, camera, renderer, controls, softBody, dynamicsWorld, softBodyMesh;

console.log('Ammo:', typeof Ammo);

Ammo().then((lib) => {
    Ammo = lib;
    init()
  });

async function init() {
    //THREE.scene setup

// Set up Ammo.js physics
    console.log('Ammo.btSoftBodyRigidBodyCollisionConfiguration is a ', Ammo.btSoftBodyRigidBodyCollisionConfiguration);
    var collisionConfiguration = new Ammo.btSoftBodyRigidBodyCollisionConfiguration();
    var dispatcher = new Ammo.btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
    var broadphase = new Ammo.btDbvtBroadphase();
    var solver = new Ammo.btSequentialImpulsevarraintSolver();
    var softBodySolver = new Ammo.btDefaultSoftBodySolver();

// ...
}

